# Vertical Aligning some text in a block <a> tag

Tags: html, css, tags, vertical-alignment

I need a css gunu out there to help me with this one.
Right I have an a tag which is a block element fixed width and height. Within it is a background image and the images title. 
I'm trying to align the text to the bottom and I'm getting no where.
I've tried doing 
display:table-cell;
vertical-align:bottom;
and all manner of different ways.
Bu getting nowhere. I know that I could do line-height but that has that weird dotted line around the element.
Just tried having a span with the text in that within the a tag and vertical align that but no joy although the underline has moved to the bottom. Which is odd!
Any help much appreciated.
Richard

Comment: It would be easier to help if you posted your current html+css.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The parent element needs display:table and then the element you want on the bottom has display:table-cell; align:bottom;

Answer (score 6):

What browsers are you targetting? This works fine for me in IE8.0.6 and FireFox 3.5.8:

```
<a style="display:block;height:200px;width:200px;background:blue;display:table-cell;vertical-align:bottom;">This is a test</a>
```

Note I've used both `display:table-cell;` and `vertical-align:bottom;`. You need 'em both; wasn't sure if you'd tried that.

If that's giving you trouble (are you targeting IE6?) you're going to have to place your `<a>` element in a block level element and then position it.

```
<div style="position:relative;top:0px;left:0px;height:200px;width:200px;background:yellow;">
    <a style="position:absolute;bottom:0px;">Your text</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm on well all the browsers. But the trouble is that I'm floating the a tag as well which means that this doesn't seem to want to play ball. least the first one doesn't in ie8 or ff3.6